# AWS SSM ping status connestion lost for windows

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssm, amazon-systems-manager, aws-ssm

Hi i am trying to perform patching activity on the ec2 instances using AWS Systems manager but unable to perform activity because in panel of SSM managed instances it shows "connection lost" for ping status.
How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Check if correct IAM role is attached to the instances also verify iSSM agent version.